# Google Recaptcha: How to force CURL over file_get_contents?

Tags: php, curl, recaptcha

I need to use `cURL` method instead of `file_get_contents()` in google recaptcha.*(using mysqli and PHP)*

By default the `file_get_contents()` is used as the request method from the file `RequestMethod/Post.php`. 
But in the server, `allow_url_fopen` is set to `0`(off), so I couldn't use this recaptcha service, `No wrapper found` error is thrown. CURL is the only way I should go for.

*changing the `allow_url_fopen` flag is NOT allowed. can't do it in htaccess, it won't work.*

I need to use CURL request method from the file `RequestMethod/CurlPost.php` and override the default `file_get_contents()`. **How to make/force cURL as default request method?**

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/recaptcha/autoload.php';
$recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha('_SECRET_KEY_');
```

and upon submitting the form, I have:

```
$resp = $recaptcha->verify($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'], $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
if ($resp->isSuccess()) {
 //my code
}
```

I thought, if default method(*file_get_contents*) fails, then alternative working method should automatically be used as request method, but it didn't. This is the library which I'm using https://github.com/google/recaptcha

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the new request method to the constructor:

```
$recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha(
    '_SECRET_KEY_',
    new \ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\CurlPost()
);
```

See https://github.com/google/recaptcha/blob/master/src/ReCaptcha/ReCaptcha.php#L59

Comment: `Fatal error: Class 'ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\CurlPost' not found in...` but error gone after I delete first `\ReCaptcha` and thus becomes `new \ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\CurlPost()`, but now curl is not working and no error thrown. The form was submitted and url refreshes and back to the same index page again.